# I have a problem using summing values in a column range on ms Excel

Tags: excel

I have a problem. Let’s say I have data (numbers) in cell `H21 to H41`, that is the data is in a cell range `H21:H41`. There are some blank cells within that cell range.  I want to sum the values of these cells in cell `K45`. And when any cell in that range changes to blank, I want the formulae to ignore the blank and calculate `(SUM)` the values of the cells in that range.

When I tried

```
=SUM(H21:H41)
```

It will return `0` as answer. 
When I tried

```
=SUM(VALUE(H21:H41)
```

and hitting `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`, it displayed the right answer. However, when i change any cell which contained a value in the cell range to blank, it will display `‘####’`.

I have tried changing the format of the cell range `H21:H41` from General to Number. But still no luck.

NB. Just to add that, the values of the cells in the range `H21:H41` are the outputs of another operation from other cells, thus, they are automatic.

Please, I really need help to resolve this issue.

In case of any doubt or need more details, please let me know.

I will really appreciate any efforts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. `###` displayed in a cell usually means either that the column is too narrow; or that you have calculated a negative time and are using the 1900 date system.  Try widening the column.  And consider editing your question so as to supply something that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @JesBet usually when excel shows "####" it means the column is to narrow to show the full contents. First ensure that the column is formatted to number, and then widen the result cell.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue either. `=SUM()` of a range does not stop working if one of the cells is emptied or set to a 0 value, and you don't have to use `VALUE()` if they're actually numbers. And `###` in a cell means the column isn't wide enough to display it; drag the column separator in the top row (or double-click it) to widen the column.

Comment: It's easy to prove that what you describe doesn't happen. Open a new workbook. Put a `1` in cells A1 through A10. In A11, type `=SUM(A1:A10)` and hit Enter. A11 shows the value `10`. Type the same exact formula in B11, which will also show `10`. Go to A5 and change the value to `0`, and watch both A11 and B11 change to `9`. Go to A4 and delete the value entirely, and watch both A11 and B11 change to `8`.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld, Rachel, Ken. Thanks for your effort. But when I tried widening the column cell, the #### changes to #VALUE! This happens when i use the formular: =SUM(VALUE(H21:H41)) since the formula: =SUM(H21:H41) does not work here.

Comment: Just to please add that ; this problem is occurring only on this particular column. This is because, I am able to sum values in the other columns using =SUM formular and which works just fine.

Comment: Hence, widening the cell range doesn’t solve the problem. I really need a solution to this.

Comment: Then you will need to provide the relevant information, as I mentioned in my first comment.  Perhaps it would help if you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JesBet if you are still having problems with this , ensure ALL the cells within the range are of the SAME number format (there are lots of number formats - pick one!) This applies to the blank cells also.  Also check  that the cells themselves don't have any value errors, as this will cause the problem also. You could try this formula : **=SUM(IF(ISERROR(H21:H41),"",H21:H41))**. This will replace errors incurred while summing up the contents of the cells with a blank value. If the sum is then not what you expect it to be, you could probably track the rogue cell. Hope this helps